# PricebookEntry Conflict Error not matching existing products

Tags: pricebookentry

I am getting an error message on a trigger that was working until recently. The issue arises on a trigger that inserts an OpportunityLineItem on an Opportunity. Here is the error:

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: unknown
>   (pricebook entry is in a different pricebook than the one assigned to
>   the opportunity):

Here is my confusion - I have a hard coded PriceBook Entry ID in the code (for now).
But this id is drawn from the correct pricebook.
To check myself, I was able to manually add an Opportunity Product and I display the Pricebook ID (via formula field).
It is the same value.
Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [Product and Schedule Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_products.htm) Data Model:

[image]

The PricebookEntry used by the OpportunityLineItem must have the same Pricebook2Id as the `Opportunity.Pricebook2Id` that you are adding it to.

E.g.

```
Id opportunityId = '006000000000001';
Id pricebookEntryId = '01u000000000001';

Opportunity opp = [Select Id, Pricebook2Id from Opportunity where Id = :opportunityId];
PricebookEntry pbe = [Select Id, Pricebook2Id from PricebookEntry where Id = :pricebookEntryId];
System.assertEquals(opp.Pricebook2Id, pbe.Pricebook2Id, 'OpportunityLineItem.PricebookEntry.Pricebook2Id should equal  OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.Pricebook2Id');
```

Comment: Yes, it did. I had no problem entering that same product from the same pricebook manually.
I changed it all to a query and the issue went away.